# When fabricating class weapons, is the chance to receive all weapons equal?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For example, when crafting a Demoman Slot token + Secondary Slot token + a scrap, the possible output is:

- Sticky Jumper
- Scottish Resistance
- Chargin' Targe
- Splendid Screen

Is the chance to get any one of those four items equal?  Or do some other weapons have a higher chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is an equal chance to craft each item.
For a Demoman Slot token + Secondary Slot token + a scrap, you have

- 25% chance for a Sticky Jumper
- 25% chance for a Scottish Resistance
- 25% chance for a Chargin' Targe
- 25% chance for a Splendid Screen

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any way to verify this?   Or have the devs specifically mentioned it as an equal chance for all weps? I want to make sure, in case I get something other than a Manmelter...

Comment: I don't have a specific dev quote, but when I was trying for my Diamondback I made 2 Ambassadors, 1 L'Etranger, and 1 Enforcer before finally getting the Diamondback. So out of 5 I got every weapon once, with 2 Ambassadors, which translates to 20% for each item and 40% for Ambassadors, but that's based on a low amount of testing, 25% for each item is most likely.